# Renderscript unrecgonized "executable" attribute

Tags: android, ant

I get below error when compiling Android apk uisng 'Android SDK Tools' version 22.0.5 & 
'Android SDK Build-Tools' 18.0.1

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:738: The following error occurred while executing this line:

build.xml:760: renderscript doesn't support the "executable" attribute

```
<property name="renderscript.target" value="${project.minSdkVersion}" />
    <renderscript executable="${renderscript}"
        includePathRefId="android.renderscript.include.path"
        genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
        resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}/raw"
        targetApi="${renderscript.target}"
        optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
        buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
        previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
    <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
</renderscript>
```

The compilation works fine with 
'Android SDK tools' : 22.0.1
'Android SDK Build-tools' : 17.

Please point out the changes i should make in build.xml

Comment: have you got any workaround to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the error, i tried removing executable and got following error

```
RenderScriptTask's 'buildToolsRoot' is required.
```

then after adding

`buildToolsRoot="${android.build.tools.dir}"` 
its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Atmaram solution works, but there were more changes there than only buildToolRoot. 
Here is a renderscript part of -code-gen target from 22.6.3 sdk tools in ...\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:

```
<property name="renderscript.target"  value="${project.minSdkVersion}" />
  <renderscript
    buildToolsRoot="${android.build.tools.dir}"
    genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
    resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}"
    rsObjFolder="${out.rs.obj.absolute.dir}"
    libsFolder="${out.rs.libs.absolute.dir}"
    targetApi="${renderscript.target}"
    optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
    supportMode="${renderscript.support.mode}"
    binFolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
    buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
    previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
  <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
</renderscript>
```